# Splitting jquery monolith file based on functionality, for smaller and quicker loading

Tags: jquery

In YUI we can use the [Configurator](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/configurator/) to get only the pieces of code we need.

**In the same way, can we split the jQuery monolith (92KB minified v 1.7.1) file as per our needs?**

Let's say for instance I decide that in my app I don't need: jQuery *animations*, *ajax*, *forms* and *dimensions*, is it possible to get a smaller version of jQuery that does not include these parts?

P.S. don't tell me to look into the code, because I did but I could not even understand where the ajax part is. The animations seem to be at `jQuery.fn.extend` (line #8233 on v.1.7.1), but what about the others?

Comment: Accept more answers and state your question completely.  I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: if you want a smaller version why not use minified version?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was -2 it was meaningful to me. I tried to edit it and make it more easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery on its own is not designed to be broken up easily (although a lot is *modular* in design) as there are a lot of dependencies. A future design goal of jQuery is to allow an *opt-in* to create your own package.

Until then, you can use [jQuip](https://github.com/mythz/jquip), or jQuery in Parts.

[Further Reading](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquip-lightweight-jquery/).

One thing you may not have considered is if you host your jQuery at the [Google CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html), there is a high chance the end user will already have the file cached. This is almost certainly more likely than they will have your modularised version of jQuery cached.

Comment: Thank Alex, I also tumbled across zepto.js -> http://zeptojs.com/ - seems to be great.... does support jquery plugins??...